# Can't use dynamic delegate parameter in lambda of expression tree

Tags: c#, lambda

I am trying to apply a simple "Where" clause on a dynamically selected table. However, the table field the clause will be applied to is also dynamic and I can't figure out how to make that part work. Getting the dynamic table works correctly.

```
using (var context = new DBEntities())
{
    var type = context.GetType();
    var tableProperty = type.GetProperty("tableName");
    var tableGet = tableProperty.GetMethod;
    var tableContent = tableGet.Invoke(context, null);
    var tableQuery = (IQueryable)tableContent;
    var tableType = tableQuery.ElementType;

    var pe = Expression.Parameter(tableType, "tableType");
    var left = Expression.PropertyOrField(pe, "fieldName");
    var right = Expression.Constant("fieldValue");
    var predicateBody = Expression.Equal(left, right);

    var whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Where", new[] { tableType },
        tableQuery.Expression, Expression.Lambda<Func<tableType, bool>>(predicateBody, pe));

    IQueryable<string> results = tableQuery.Provider.CreateQuery<string>(whereCallExpression);
}
```

This block of code will not compile because of `Expression.Lambda<Func<tableType, bool>>(predicateBody, pe)`. If I hard-code types for the Expression-related code, this sample runs and returns the expected results.

Comment: If you're going to make literally *everything* dynamic like this, you're better off just not using EF in the first place.  Use more traditional methods of executing DB queries that are already inherently dynamic in nature.  EF is advantageous in its ability to restrict the queries to those that are statically valid, which is a feature that's only making your life hard.

Comment: Unfortunately, the feature that is driving this particular functionality was added months after development on the project began. Everything else about the project (99% of it) is perfectly fine with EF.

Comment: So then let the other 99% of the project use EF, and let this one feature use something else, given that EF isn't suited to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does not compile because `tableType`, a variable of type `System.Type`, cannot be used as a type parameter of a generic function.

However, you should be able to make this compile and run by replacing a call to generic `Lambda<Func<...>>` with a call to non-generic `Lambda`:

```
var whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Where", new[] { tableType },
    tableQuery.Expression, Expression.Lambda(predicateBody, pe));
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! I also had to change my last line to `IQueryable results = tableQuery.Provider.CreateQuery(whereCallExpression);`